# In Slick (Scala), how to refactor codes like this?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

I see codes like this:

```
trait LoginInfoRepoImpl extends LoginInfoRepo {

  def loginInfoRepository = new LoginInfoRepository {
    private val loginInfoTable = TableQuery[LoginInfoTable]

    // return a LoginID
    def save(userLoginInfo: userLoginInfo): Future[userLoginID] = Future {
      val newRecord = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
        loginInfoTable.filter(
          l => l.userID === userLoginInfo.userID &&
          (l.deviceID === userLoginInfo.deviceID || (l.deviceID.isEmpty && userLoginInfo.userID.isEmpty))).list.headOption.fold {
          val newSubID = loginInfoTable.filter(l => l.userID === userLoginInfo.userID).sortBy(_.subID.desc).take(1).map(_.subID).list.headOption.getOrElse(0) + 1
          (loginInfoTable returning loginInfoTable) += LoginInfoRecord(userLoginInfo.userID, newSubID, userLoginInfo.deviceID, userLoginInfo.userAgent, getCurrentTime)
        } { l =>
          // to do : update time
          val q = for (l <- loginInfoTable if l.userID === userLoginInfo.userID && ((l.deviceID === userLoginInfo.deviceID)
            || (l.deviceID.isEmpty && userLoginInfo.userID.isEmpty)))
            yield l.lastLoginTime
          q.updateReturning(loginInfoTable.map(identity), getCurrentTime).head
        }
      }
      userLoginID(newRecord.userID, newRecord.subID.toString)
    }

  }
}
```

This looks a little monstrous for me. I found many things are crowded into one line. Also, I found `l.deviceID` is of type `Column[Option[String]]`, while `userLoginInfo.deviceID` is of type`Option[String]`, they don't equal if both of them is `None`. Thus a `l.device.isEmpty` looks necessary..

Does anyone have suggestions about how to refactor these codes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Better indentation and breaking up long lines.

Slick-specific: pull queries out of the withSession block and reuse them for shared logic. Use firstOption instead of .list.headOption.

Side-note: Since you are generating IDs based on old ones, you may want to use a transaction or use a more efficient means provided by your DB.

```
trait LoginInfoRepoImpl extends LoginInfoRepo {
  def loginInfoRepository = new LoginInfoRepository {
    private val loginInfoTable = TableQuery[LoginInfoTable]

    // return a LoginID
    def save(userLoginInfo: userLoginInfo): Future[userLoginID] = Future {
      val userLoginInfoQuery = loginInfoTable.filter(l => l.userID === userLoginInfo.userID)
      val deviceLoginInfoQuery = userLoginInfoQuery.filter(
        l =>
          l.deviceID === userLoginInfo.deviceID ||
          (
            l.deviceID.isEmpty && userLoginInfo.userID.isEmpty
          )
        )
      val subIdQuery = userLoginInfoQuery.sortBy(_.subID.desc).map(_.subID)
      val newRecord = DB.withTransaction{ implicit session =>
        deviceLoginInfoQuery
          .firstOption
          .fold {
            val newSubID = subIdQuery.firstOption.getOrElse(0) + 1
            val newLoginInfo = LoginInfoRecord(userLoginInfo.userID, newSubID, userLoginInfo.deviceID, userLoginInfo.userAgent, getCurrentTime)
            (loginInfoTable returning loginInfoTable) += newLoginInfo
          }( _ =>
            // to do : update time
            deviceLoginInfoQuery
              .map(_.lastLoginTime)
              .updateReturning(loginInfoTable.map(identity), getCurrentTime)
              .head
          )
      }
      userLoginID(newRecord.userID, newRecord.subID.toString)
    }

  }
}
```